# A Popular Lady?

Tags: logical-deduction

Anita, Becky, Claire and Donna went to visit Emmy on Saturday.

1. The times were as follows:

   - Anita visited at 8'00,
   - Becky at 9'00,
   - Claire at 10'00, and
   - Donna at 11'00.
2. At least one woman visited Emmy between Anita and Becky.
3. Anita did not visit Emmy before both Claire and Donna.
4. Claire did not visit Emmy between Becky and Donna.

Who visited Emmy last?

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling!! I have a question/maybe I'm misunderstanding. How does 1, with the times, work with 2-4?

Comment: Here's a hint: Even a broken clock is right twice a day...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The times were as follows:
Anita visited at 8'00, Becky at 9'00, Claire at 10'00, and Donna at 11'00.

> Some times are AM, some are PM, changing the order:
> Becky(9A), Donna(11A), Anita(8P), Claire(10P)

At least one woman visited Emmy between Anita and Becky.

> Donna visits between Anita and Becky

Anita did not visit Emmy before both Claire and Donna.

> Anita visits before Claire, but not also Donna

Claire did not visit Emmy between Becky and Donna.

> Nobody visited between Becky and Donna

Who visited Emmy last?

> Claire

Comment: Great answer. OP does not mention it was a particular Saturday. If Saturdays are also different then could be many answers??